# How do I run excel using all the default add-ins from Python win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com

```
import win32com
import win32com.client as win32

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDisplatch('Excel.Application')
```

This fires up Excel, but for whatever reason none of the plugins load.

If Excel was already loaded, the plugins will stay loaded and be accessible.

Please advise.

**Context:** I'm scraping data from a worksheet that makes calls using a proprietary plugin. If the plugin doesn't load, all the cells I need to scrape just throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add the code to access your plugin in a macro and then automate the macro from Python.

```
xl.Run("Book1.xls!Macro1")
```

Answer (score 0):

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDisplatch('Excel.Application')

typos here.

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')